# JSON deserialization returns {null,null} for KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, json.net

I've declared the below key:value pair in JSON:

```
"saleParameters": [
        {"saleName":"FlashSale2018"},
  ]
```

I'm mapping the above using the below property in my contract class:

```
    [JsonProperty("saleParameters")]
    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> SaleParameters { get; set; }
```

But for some reason, I always receive null values in SaleParameters after deserialization. I'm using NewtonSoft.JSON for JSON serialize/deserialize, code is running on .net core.

Any idea on why this is happening and how to solve this ?

Comment: [Clue](http://rextester.com/GWEEP43348). Are the keys of SaleParameters unique?

Comment: Pardon me, but I didn't get it. If it's working in that editor, why is it not working with the above format ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your [current code expects JSON like this](http://rextester.com/ATAF17823):

```
"saleParameters": [
    {"Key": "saleName", "Value": "FlashSale2018"}]
]
```

You should use a dictionary instead:

```
public IEnumerable<IDictionary<string,string>> SaleParameters { get; set; }
```

This will deserialize "saleName" as they key and "FlashSale2018" as the value. And, if you really need `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`, you can call `SaleParameters.SelectMany(p => p). ToEnumerable()`.

Comment: Actually, since the outer JSON container is an array, it needs to be `public IEnumerable<Dictionary<string,string>> SaleParameters { get; set; }`.  Then you can do `SaleParameters.SelectMany(d => d).ToList();` to get a flat list.

Comment: @dbc Oops. Yup.